# Do I need two aws_iam_policy_document in this ecs fargate script?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here is my terraform script

```
variable "aws_region" { }
variable "flavor" { }  # test or prod
variable "task_worker_service_name" { }
variable "task_cpu" {}
variable "task_memory" {}
variable "az_count" {}

terraform {
  required_version = "= 0.12.6"
}

provider "aws" {
  version = "~> 2.21.1"
  region = "${var.aws_region}"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ecs_service_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [ "ecs.amazonaws.com" ]
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "task_worker_iam_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions   = [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [
        "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      ]
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [ "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com" ]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_service_role" {
  name = "${var.flavor}-task-ecs-service-role"
  path = "/"
  assume_role_policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.ecs_service_policy.json}"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_service_role_attachment" {
  role = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_service_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "ecs" {
    cidr_block  = "10.0.0.0/16"
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
    enable_dns_support = true
    instance_tenancy = "default"

    tags = {
      Name = "ecs"
    }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "vpc_ecs_task_worker" {
    name        = "${var.flavor}-vpc_ecs_task_worker"
    description = "ECS Allowed Ports"

    ingress {
        from_port       = 32768
        to_port         = 65535
        protocol        = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }


    egress {
        from_port       = 0
        to_port         = 0
        protocol        = "-1"
        cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }

}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
  name = "${var.flavor}-ecs-task-worker-task-execution-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "task_worker_iam_role" {
    name = "${var.flavor}-task-worker-role"
    path = "/"
    assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.task_worker_iam_role_policy.json
}

# Create var.az_count private subnets, each in a different AZ
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count             = "${var.az_count}"
  cidr_block        = "${cidrsubnet(aws_vpc.ecs.cidr_block, 8, count.index)}"
  availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
  vpc_id            = "${aws_vpc.ecs.id}"
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_worker" {
  family = "${var.flavor}-${var.task_worker_service_name}"
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu = var.task_cpu
  memory = var.task_memory
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn
  task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.task_worker_iam_role.arn
  container_definitions = <<JSON
[
{
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": null,
      "entryPoint": null,
      "portMappings": [],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": ${var.task_cpu},
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": ${var.task_memory},
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "us-west-2.amazonaws.com/task:4383669",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "task-worker"
    }
  ]
JSON
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "task_pool" {
  name = "${var.flavor}-task-pool"
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "task_service" {
  name = "${var.flavor}-task-worker-service"

  cluster = "${aws_ecs_cluster.task_pool.id}"

  task_definition = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.task_worker.arn}"

  launch_type = "FARGATE"

  desired_count = 2

  network_configuration {
    subnets = "${aws_subnet.private[*].id}"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.vpc_ecs_task_worker.id}" ]
    assign_public_ip = "true"
  }

}
```

In this script I have added two 'aws_iam_policy_document':

`data "aws_iam_policy_document" "pdf_conversion_iam_role_policy"`, and
`data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy"` respectively

They are basically identical i.e.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [ "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com" ]
    }
  }
}
```

I used `assume_role_policy` in `aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role` and `pdf_conversion_iam_role_policy` in `aws_iam_role.pdf_conversion_iam_role`.

My question is: Is it necessary to have two `aws_iam_policy_document` in this case? Also do you have a good suggestion for a naming convention for this kind of terraform resource names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of Terraform then you can potentially write this using the resource `for_each` feature to produce multiple instances of `aws_iam_policy_document` from a single `data` block:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role" {
  for_each = toset([
    "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com",
    "ecs.amazonaws.com",
  ])

  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = [each.value]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "service" {
  for_each = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role

  name               = "${var.flavor}-${each.key}-service-role"
  assume_role_policy = each.value.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_service" {
  role = aws_iam_role.service["ecs.amazonaws.com"].name

  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceRole"
}
```

`for_each` inside a `data` or `resource` block makes references to the resource produce a map of resource objects. In this case, our map keys are the service identifiers. That gives us some resources with the following addresses:

- `data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role["ecs.amazonaws.com"]`
- `data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]`
- `aws_iam_role.service["ecs.amazonaws.com"]`
- `aws_iam_role.service["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]`

The `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.ecs_service` resource then refers directly to the specific role object for `ecs.amazonaws.com`, allowing it to represent the policy that is uniquely attached to that role even though we generalized the creation of the roles themselves.

We can add more service identifiers to the `for_each` in `data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role"`, or possibly even factor this pattern out into a module that takes the set of service hostnames as an input variable and exports the role names via an output value, if you find yourself creating lots of these.

Comment: I made a generalized version of this into a public Terraform module, in case it's useful for reducing boilerplate: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/apparentlymart/service-roles/aws